# How to load HTML file into <editor>

Tags: javascript, file-io, xul

I'm trying to figure out how to get my XUL app to open an HTML file and load it into an editor element.  However, documentation is sparse.

Right now, I have a content window like so:

```xml
<hbox id="main-frame" flex="1">
    <tabbox id="workspace-tabbox" flex="1">
        <tabs id="workspace-tabs"/>
        <tabpanels id="workspace-tabpanels" flex="1" context="clipmenu"/>
    </tabbox>
    <splitter id="main-frame-splitter"/>
    <iframe id="preview-frame" src="about:blank" flex="1"/>
</hbox>
```

With javascript I append a `<tab>` to the `<tabs>`, and a `<tabpanel>` to the `<tabpanels>`.  I then create an `<editor>`, append it to the `<tabpanel>`, and make it editable.

Then, there is an Open button linked to this function:

```javascript
function promptFile() {
    var filepicker = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker);
    var file;
    var choice;
    var path = null;

    filepicker.init(window, "Open", filepicker.modeOpen);
    filepicker.appendFilters(filepicker.filterHTML);
    choice = filepicker.show();

    if (choice == filepicker.returnOK) {
        file = filepicker.file.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
        path = file.path;
    }

    return path;
}
```

From here, I don't know how to load it into the `<editor>`.  I'm also not sure if I'm on the right path getting the 'path', or if I need to do something with the 'file' object, instead.

Any insight or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't duplicate the tags in the title of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<editor>` is essentially a frame - you simply need to load the correct URL into that frame. You can use [`nsIIOService.newFileURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIOService#newFileURI%28%29) to get that URL from an `nsIFile` instance:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var uri = Services.io.newFileURI(file);
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
var loadFlags = Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE;
editor.webNavigation.loadURI(uri.spec, loadFlags, null, null, null);
editor.makeEditable("html", true);
```

For reference: [`nsIWebNavigation.loadURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebNavigation#loadURI%28%29)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This works great, except for one thing - it loads the html file as a rendered HTML page.  Maybe I didn't word my original question correctly, but what I want is to load the source code (html tags) into the editor.  I've tried loading the URI into the editor directly as the "src" attribute, but it generated an error message ("The file chrome://app/content/[xpconnect wrapped nsIURI] cannot be found").

Comment: In addition, I also tried loading the path ("file.path") into the editor directly as the "src" attribute.  That generated a different error message ("c is not a registered protocol").

Comment: @AndrewHuth: `<editor>` is a WYSIWYG editor, it is the wrong choice if you want to edit source code. You probably want [source-editor.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/source-editor.jsm) (use `setMode(SourceEditor.MODES.HTML)` and `setText()` with the text you get from the file).